# Getting 400 error in Wcf restfull hosted service in iis server

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis

Declaration of function with json configuration

```
namespace Wcf_Test2
 {

 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IMyService
 {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "dowork")]
    string DoWork();
 }
 }
```

It is function that returns string value.

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public string DoWork()
    {
        string str = "HI, Its's DOWork Running"; 
        return str;
    }
}
```

This is Web.config file which I use.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="Wcf_Test2.MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
 contract="Wcf_Test2.IMyService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
 contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Wcf_Test2/MyService.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
 </services>
 <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Default">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

I am calling this hosted web service as http://localhost/Wcf_Test2/MyService.svc/dowork
but it's replying this

[The error is this which this picture is showing me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8uD6.png)

Comment: Don't insert code in images.

Comment: Thank you for reply. plz solve error if you can.

Comment: What is the name of the web application in IIS?

Comment: @S.Dav it's name is Wcf_Test2.